# When are two classes with same definition and classpath chosen ambiguously in Scala with SBT and Ivy?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, classpath, ivy

In Scala, using sbt, I'm curious what I can expect if I:

1. Define two different classes with same name, definition, and classpath in two differently named libraries (imagine `case class User(name: String, age: Int)` in two places, but one has `require(age >= 0)`)
2. Depend on those two libraries in `build.sbt`
3. Reference that class in code that successfully compiles and passes tests
4. Publish that code as a library that is then run elsewhere

My specific question is, **At what points are those classes chosen ambiguously?** That is, at what points of the compilation, publishing, and application launch processes might the prevailing class alternate between one definition and the other?

This is for a Play Framework application, though I don't think it makes a difference. Also this is for SBT v0.13, which uses Ivy for dependency management.

Answer (score 5):

Given two classes of exactly the same fully qualified name exist on the classpath, then which one gets loaded is determined by the **order** they appear on the classpath. We can see the order on `Compile` classpath by executing

```
show Compile / fullClasspath
```

For example, say project `multi1` depends on `common1` and `common2`, then in the following scenario

```
sbt:multi1> show Compile / fullClasspath
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/sbt-multi-project-example/multi1/target/scala-2.12/classes)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/sbt-multi-project-example/common2/target/scala-2.12/classes)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/sbt-multi-project-example/common1/target/scala-2.12/classes)
```

the class form `common2` will be loaded because it comes before `common1` on the classpath. We can similarly check the order on the `Runtime` classpath

```
show Runtime / fullClasspath
```

I believe there is nothing more intelligent than the order precedence out-of-the-box.

As a side note, sbt does provide [eviction warnings](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Eviction+warning) in the case of *different versions* of the same library are resolved.